# Selecting text in RichTexbox in C# deletes the text

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have typed in the following text in  a control derived from Richtextbox

"The world is {beautful}".

My main intention is to create a link for the word beautful. I can create this using CFE_LINK , but that's when I select the text.

**When I use Select (4,9), the text within the range 4 to 9 gets deleted.**

Can someone please help me with what I am missing out?

CODE :

I am creating a User Control, derived from Richtextbox.

I am giving the exact code below; I have not done any color change. I think the Select command sets the selected text to blue by default.

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   String keypressed =  e.KeyChar.ToString();
   if(keypressed == "}")
      Select(4,9)        
   base.OnKeyPress(e);
}
```

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: A code snippet would be a great help here.

Comment: and also, care to post some code so we can see exactly what your doing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; the text gets selected (but note that it might not show unless the rtf is the active control)

Comment: any chance your highlight color is the same as the text color?  that would make the text look like it isn't there although it still is.

Comment: Update the post with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first when I started messing with this, I was puzzled as well. But then it hit me, it's very possible that your key that's being pressed is being sent to the textbox to render at KeyUp. Sure enough, when I changed your code to this it worked:

```
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Oem6)
        {
           Select(4, 9);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This looks good. In fact I would like to thank everyone for their views. Any idea how to get the index of the character I typed. Any better alternative than GetPositionFromCharIndex ; as in this case I can have many { } and need to maintain a list for all these.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that when the '}' key is pressed, your code runs before the character is sent to the textbox.

So you select the text, and then the '}' character is sent to the textbox, overwriting the selection.

**Edit:** Yup, reproduced it.

I'm not sure off the top of my head how to solve it. Perhaps it would be better to implement `OnTextChanged` instead.. You could scan the entire textbox for unlinked {words inside braces}. It might be slower if the text is large, but it would automatically handle copy and paste and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

I voted for BFree's answer, but if for some reason you must use OnKeyPress method, you can invoke the select method, so it happens after the event has completed.

```
    protected delegate void SelectAfterKeyPress(int start, int length);

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
        String keypressed = e.KeyChar.ToString();
        if (keypressed == "}")
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new SelectAfterKeyPress(Select), new object[] { 4, 9 });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892370/selecting-text-in-richtexbox-in-c-deletes-the-text/892888#892888)'s answer, you are selecting the text first, and then the "`}`" is typed into the textbox, replacing your selection. Maybe what you want is to type the "`}`" first and *then* make the selection.

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   // type "}" into textbox
   base.OnKeyPress(e);

   String keypressed =  e.KeyChar.ToString();

   if(keypressed == "}")
      Select(4,9)        
}
```